# how to redirect IP to a Server based on his geographical location

Tags: ip, redirect

I have to servers :

10.10.10.10 and 10.10.10.11 both has the same domain name mydomin.com the idea is to to redirect for example visitors from Europe to 10.10.10.10 but visitors from US should redirect to 10.10.10.11 but they still use the same domain name www.mydomain.com

Anyone has an idea how to do that ??

Thanks PPs

Comment: **TL;DR** - GeoDNS

Answer (score 1):

Have you done any research on the topic? http://www.f5.com/it-management/solutions/global-load-balancing/overview/

While it is not trivial to implement... it certainly is not impossible. Generally speaking, it sounds like a Geographically sensitive DNS server would be your best bet. There are patches to allow Bind to do this in a split horizon setup.

Perhaps you would care to detail your setup. It might help get a definitive answer rather than a bunch of down votes.